# Storing one column of a database table into an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a Program which tracks the movement of an RFID Tag as it moves between RFID censors. This is mimicking the movement of a wallet between rooms. Each censor will be a door to a different room.

I have a SQLite database which holds the Name of the Card, the Location, and the name of the Tag to differentiate between different cards.

I need an ArrayList which tells me what Tags are currently on the database.

I have a DAO method that displays all the values in a database and stores it in an ArrayList as shown:

```
SELECT * FROM Wallets;
[name: Henry, location: 0, tag: 5c00ce6df0, name: jim, location: 0, tag: wallet1]
```

I am trying to write another DAO method that will just display the tags like this:

```
SELECT Tag FROM Wallets;
[5c00ce6df0, wallet1]
```

Once i have these values saved in an ArrayList i intend to pass them into another DAO method which takes the tags and returns all the relevant information, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Wallets WHERE Tag = 'wallet1';
name: jim, location: 0, tag: wallet1
```

Here is the code for my `getAllWallets()` DAO:

```
public ArrayList<Wallet> getAllWallets() throws SQLException{
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Wallets;";
    ArrayList<Wallet> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(query);
        // execute SQL query
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

    while (resultset.next()) {
        Wallet w = new Wallet(query, 0, query);

        w.setName(resultset.getString("Name"));
        w.setLocation(resultset.getInt("Location"));
        w.setTag(resultset.getString("Tag"));
        list.add(w);
        }   
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        resultset.close();
        statement.close();
        dbConnection.close();
        }   
    return list;
    }
```

Here is what i have tried so far for my `getWalletTag()` DAO:

```
public ArrayList<String> getWalletTag() throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String query = "SELECT Tag FROM Wallets;";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        // execute SQL query
        System.out.println(query);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

        String tag = tag.toString(); // i know this is totally wrong but i got stuck

        list.add(tag);

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    finally 
    {
        if (resultset != null) {
        resultset.close();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
        dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

What i am struggling with is how to get all the values of the Tag column into an array list. Is there an easy way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where's the Java source code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If this is going to be a heavily data driven application, I might suggest using an ORM.  It lets you access database information via Java and load it into objects that have been created for you based on the database schema.  I've used several over the years in various languages.  In Java, I've been using jOOQ with good success.  https://www.jooq.org/

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger I have edited it to show my source code

Comment: @Evan oh right that sounds good, could you point me in the right direction for that so i can look into it?

Comment: @StaticBeagle im not sure what you mean by this, currently Tag is the primary key in my database

Comment: The link at the end of my first comment will take you to www.jooq.org.  This is the website for jOOQ, the Java ORM I've had good success with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an "ideal universe", you would probably want to use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (like Hibernate), and a framework (like [Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-spring-boot)).

Either or both might be "overkill" for your application.

If your goal is to get a "list of tags", then the code you've got looks OK:

- Connect to the database.
- Make a query.
- Copy the resultset into a list of Java objects, one at a time.
- Close the DB connection when you're done.

If your goal is to "optimally" find a *specific* tag (without making another DB query), then perhaps you should use a Java [Map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)  or [Set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/) instead of an ArrayList.

Should you wish to consider Spring Boot and Sqlite, here are a couple of tutorials:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite
- http://code-flow-hjbello.blogspot.com/2017/07/using-sqlite-with-jdbc.html

This part of your code seems good:

```
public ArrayList<Wallet> getAllWallets() throws SQLException{
   resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
   while (resultset.next()) {
     Wallet w = new Wallet(query, 0, query);
     w.setName(resultset.getString("Name"));
     w.setLocation(resultset.getInt("Location"));
     w.setTag(resultset.getString("Tag"));
     list.add(w);
   }   
   ...
```

So one of two choices:

1. Either *forget* about `getWalletTag()`, and just use your wallets to identify tags, or
2. Use the same query, just save the "tag" column into your array list (instead of anything else).

Option 2:

```
 public ArrayList<String> getWalletTag() throws SQLException {
   String query = "SELECT Tag FROM Wallets;";
   ...
   resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
   List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (resultset.next()) {
     tags.add(resultset.getString("Tag"));
     ...
```

... or ...

```
     ...
   Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
   while (resultset.next()) {
     tags.add(resultset.getString("Tag"));
```

Comment: Yes! Thats it, it option 2 worked for me! thank you very much. this is for uni coursework so if i have time at the end i will look into optimizing with Map or Set however this is good enough for now haha. Thanks again much appreciated.